# Center and Right div Positioning

Tags: css, html, css-position, vertical-alignment, absolute

I am trying to center one div on my page and have the other attached to the right side of the window like so:

```
            header
   |----------------------|
   |      _______    _____|
   |     |       |   |   ||
   |     |       |   |   ||
   |     | div a |   | b ||
   |     |       |   |   ||
   |     |_______|   |___||
   |----------------------|
            footer
```

Div a is positioned using margin: 0 auto; and div b needs to be the same height as div a. I can get this to work with position:absolute, but it pulls my footer up under my divs. Here's what I have currently:

```
#a{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
}

#b{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    right:0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Right now, div b is on the right, but under div a. How can I align these vertically without having my footer be affected by absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your problem is that your absolutely positioned div has no relatively positioned parent.

You can try this:

```
.container
{
 position:relative;
 }

#a
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 800px;
border: 1px solid green;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
}

#b
{
position: absolute;
display:block;
right:0;
top:0;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid blue;
padding-right: 15px;
margin-left: 10px;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

then your html would be as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. However, now I have a second vertical scrollbar. How can I get this container to fit the size of my divs?

Comment: Hi, you can adjust its size to accommodate your padding and maybe (as a last resort) set the .container overflow value to "hidden" to remove scrolling

Comment: How could I do this if my pages are of variable length? This is part of a larger wordpress custom template I am putting together? Perhaps a jQuery solution?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though div a is 30px from the top of the screen. Since div b is absolutely positioned, all you need to do is set a position from the top. Add this to your `#b` css:

```
#b{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    right:0px;
    top:30px;
    ...
}
```

That will position it at the same height. (assuming div a is actually 30px from the top)